# Keras dependencies needed for prediction only in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, keras, aws-lambda

I'm trying to package my trained Keras classifier models (Theano backend) and their HDF5 weights as AWS Lambda functions that process classification requests coming from an API. Lambda has a 50MB limit for the zip file that contains the function code **and** dependencies, so I'm wondering whether any of the dependencies needed for training are not needed for prediction, so that I can leave them out of the Lambda zip file. Right now I'm just squeaking by at ~45MB with all dependencies (numpy, scipy, etc.), but I'd like to drop any dead weight if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip your binaries to save space

```
find . | xargs strip
```